# Network error unable to reach the server when view contract with CiviHR

Tags: civihr

I have installed CiviHR (extension) version 1.6.11 on wordpress.
When I view the Job Contract in the Contact Information, I got the error message "Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again."
Check the console of the browser, I saw the browser received 500 Server error when request to address

> http://192.168.0.121/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contact/view/hrjobcontract&cid=205&snippet=json

The detail in the image below:
[image]

Please help me to fix this problem. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have detected the issued.
I open apache log and saw the error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function file_upload_max_size() in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/hrjobcontract/CRM/Hrjobcontract/Page/JobContractTab.php on line 46

So I go to the directory and edit that. Because the default value for max size when upload contract file is 10MB. So I change that. Every thing work well now.
[image]